# How to use 220v relay switch to stat/stop a 110v motor?

Tags: relay

How do I use a 220v well pump pressure switch to start/stop a small 110v motor using a relay switch? When the pump comes on the motor should as well.

Comment: single pole or dual pole pressure switch?

Answer (score 0):

From your discription, is this what you think of?

[image]

---

@fraxinus - like this?
[image]

Comment: If it is in the US, N is in the middle of the two 110 that make 220.